# Jquery Cycle Carousel with varying slide height

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle

I have created a Carousel using malsup jquery cycle.

My problem is i want the pager or pagination to be snug to the bottom of the each slides content.

At the moment the plugin works out the largest slide height and apply this to the container - thus creating large white space on the slides with less content. see here:

http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/chaos2013/index1.html

I see in the malup documentation you can add 'containerResize: 0' to stop this from happening but as you see from my second example below as soon as i do this the content disappears:

http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/chaos2013/index.html

Ive tried adding a height: 100% or height: auto to the containing div but this does nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

overflow: hidden in the below line of code is hiding the content when we set the 0 to containerResize. This style is getting added from the jquery.cycle.all plugin code. You may have to modify the script to get the content displayed.

```
<div class="allSlidesWrap slideshow" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: i can remove overflow hidden in firebug or override it with !important css and although the content shows the pager appears above the content rahter than below because the containing div still doesnt work out an 100% height. Thanks but this is not the answer

Comment: In the end i used another plugin (anything slider) which i amended to acheive the required effect. Those of you who want to see it working please see: http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/chaos2013/NEW/

Comment: Anything slider was a nightmare making responsive so im now using 'FlexSlider' responsive carousel. See it working nicely here: http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/chaos2013/NEW/